# sliders outside of a table to dynamically update table contents

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, uislider

I have a table that I'm using jquery to sort, and would like to add some slider bars above the table which I can use which allow me to adjust the cell values of the table.

I have the following code (which I can use a few of in a row), which will work to create a few slider bars and update their output. However, it I insert this in with the code I have for the jquery table, this code does not appear to be read.

code:

```
$(function() {
        $( "#SliderBar1" ).slider({
            value:0,
            min: 0,
            max: 5,
            step: 1,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount1" ).val( ui.value );
            }
        });
        $( "#setvalue" ).click(function(){
            $( "#amount1" ).val( 3 );
            $( "#SliderBar1" ).slider("option", "value", 3);
        });
        $( "#amount1" ).val($( "#SliderBar1" ).slider( "value" ) );
    });
```

I also have this which will use the HTML5 slider bar (preferred if possible), but if I have more than one of these, it does not seem to keep the output separate and will just update one of the outputs.

```
Bar: <input name="SliderBarA" type="range"  min="0" max="5" value="0" onchange="showValue(this.value)"/>
        <span id="SliderBarA">0</span>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function showValue(newValue){
                document.getElementById("SliderBarA").innerHTML = newValue;
            };
        </script>
```

In either case, the values of the slider bars need to then be pulled into the table and when updated, update for calculated values in the table.

For argument's sake let's say I have a column in the table of {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} that I would like to multiply by the value of one of the slider bars, and then add the value of the other slider bar to that value:

```
column value = table value * sliderbar1 value + sliderbar2 value
```

I have the following for my table:

```
$(function () {




    DataArray = [];
    ObjectsArray = ['Object_01', 'Object_02', 'Object_03', 'Object_04', 'Object_05'];
    DataArray.push(['Col_00', 'Col_01', 'Col_02', 'Col_03', 'Col_04', 'Col_05']);
    Col3Array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    Col4Array = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    Col5Array = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15];

    for (var i = 0; i < ObjectsArray.length; i++) {
        tempor = [];
        tempor.push(i)
        tempor.push(ObjectsArray[i]);
        tempor.push(    '<input name="a" type="range"  min="0" max="5" value="0"/>'
                    +   '<br>Value: '
                    +   '<output>0</output>');
        tempor.push((Col3Array[i]*.9).toString() + '<br>(' + (Col3Array[i]).toString() + ')');
        tempor.push((Col4Array[i]*.9).toString() + '<br>(' + (Col4Array[i]).toString() + ')');
        tempor.push((Col5Array[i]));
        DataArray.push(tempor);
    }
    DataArray.push(['Col_00', 'Col_01', 'Col_02', 'Col_03', 'Col_04', 'Col_05']);

    $('#namehere').tablesorter({debug: true,
        theme: 'blue',
        widgetOptions: {
            build_type: 'array',
            build_source: DataArray,
            build_headers: {
                rows: 1, // Number of header rows from the csv
                classes: [], // Header classes to apply to cells
                text: [], // Header cell text
                widths: [] // set header cell widths
            },
            build_footers: {
                rows: 1, // Number of header rows from the csv
                classes: [], // Footer classes to apply to cells
                text: [] // Footer cell text
            }
        },
        initialized: function (table) {
            $('#namehere').on('change', 'input', function () {
                var $input = $(this),
                    $td = $input.closest('td'),
                    // don't allow resort, it makes it difficult to use the slider
                    resort = false;
                $td
                    .find('output').html($input.val())
                    .end() // back to $td
                    .prev().prev()  //  to Col_00 column
                    var $row = $td.prev().prev().html();
                $td
                    .find('output').html($input.val())
                    .end() // back to $td
                    .next() // to Col_03 column
                    .html((Math.round( Col3Array[$row]*(parseFloat($input.val())*.2) *100)/100).toString()
                        + '<br>(' + Col3Array[$row].toString() + ')');
                $td
                    .find('output').html($input.val())
                    .end()
                    .next().next() // to Col_04 column
                    .html((Math.round( Col4Array[$row]*(parseFloat($input.val())*.2) *100)/100).toString()
                        + '<br>(' + Col4Array[$row].toString() + ')');
                // update the entire table since multiple cells have changed
                $(table).trigger('update', [ resort ])
            }).change(); // trigger change event to set initial values
        }
    });
});
```

I would like to place 2 slider bars above the table this creates and call their values into the calculated cells.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Make a JSFiddle with the relevant parts.

Comment: You should be able to use pretty much the same code (from the initialized function) from your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771456/cell-computation-for-tablesorter). Take that demo and update it with sliders if you need more help.

Comment: Tried to get it for awhile, but each time I try something it seems that the table disappears or something else that I'm wanting doesn't work anymore. I've updated the question above to provide the code I have for the table.